# How to center a Column which have row as child in container parent

Tags: flutter

[image]

I want to set the A image to the center like B images without the last 2 widgets being centered.
Right now here is the code

```
Container(
 child: Column(
  children: [
   Row(
    children: [],
   ),
  ],
 ),
)
```

[image]

This is what I want to achieve and still can't found the solution. Column crossAlignment to center not solved the problem.

Comment: you may want to use crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center in column and mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center in Row

Comment: the result will be like images B, the result I wanted to achieve is like the image below @ibhavikmakwana

Answer (score 0):

You achieve it by doing this

```
Container(
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '1',
            ),
            Text(
              '1',
            ),
            Text(
              '1',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              '2',
            ),
            Text(
              '2',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey You need to keep in mind about the cros saxis and main axis alignment,
Cross axis alignment for a column is the horizontal axis i,e along the x-axis in the graph. and for Row the cross axis is along the vertical axis i,e your y-axis

you can modify them however you want to get the desired alignment.

```
return Container(
 child: Column(
   crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
   children: <Widget>[
     Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: <Widget>[
         Container(
           width: 20,
           height: 20,
           color: Colors.green,
         ),
         Container(
           width: 20,
           height: 20,
           color: Colors.blue,
         ),
         Container(
           width: 20,
           height: 20,
           color: Colors.red,
         ),
       ],
     ),
     SizedBox(
       height: 10,
     ),
     Row(
       mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
       children: <Widget>[
         Container(
           width: 20,
           height: 20,
           color: Colors.red,
         ),
         SizedBox(
           width: 10,
         ),
         Container(
           width: 20,
           height: 20,
           color: Colors.red,
         ),
       ],
     ),
   ],
 ),
);
```